# Use function output as input to another function

Tags: python, python-2.7

My question exactly is i want to use function output as input to another function,

Like:

```
def first(one,two):
    #some codes gives me info from json files
    api_data = json.loads(api.text)
    return api_data["response"]["info"][one][two];

def second(moreinfo):
    #this code is using first function and gives me the result to do something else on it, beside i want the first function as it is, because i'm using it in the project.
    api_data = json.loads(api.text)
    return api_data[moreinfo]["data"]["name"];
```

I'm using this in the file to get the result from second function

```
second(""+str(first(one,"two"))+"")
```

And i got this error

```
return api_data[first(one,"two")]["data"]["name"]
KeyError: 'data'
```

I think this error because first(one,"two") in second function doesn't took,
because i tried to put

```
return api_data["1"]["data"]["name"]
```

And its work with giving me info for number 1 result from first function,

Thanks and Regards :)

**EDITED**

Some examples for json

(for first function)

```
{
    "response": {
        "info": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "desc": "desc"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Second example (i want to print this in second function)

```
{
  "1": {
    "data": {
      "name": "Name"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you print `api_data`?

Comment: Yes, can you show example `api_data`  contents?

Comment: Did you try `second(str(first(one,"two")))`

Comment: @Jack Hughes, Ok, Now examples in question,

Comment: @AndMar Yes i tried it, nothing change, same problem

Comment: what is `api_data`?

Comment: The problem is not caused by the use of pyqt so it is not necessary to place those tags

Comment: @eyllanesc which tags?

Comment: In your functions this returns some value of api_data, ask how you have defined that variable.

Comment: TAG: `pyqt` and `pyqt4`

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry, this is `api_data`,  `api_data = json.loads(api.text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem when i use PyQt, but if i just try the code without PyQt its work fine so, the question is no longer not solved.

```
def first(one,two):
    api = requests.get("url")
    api_data = json.loads(api.text)
    return api_data["response"]["info"][one][two]

def second(id):
    api = requests.get("another-url")
    api_data = json.loads(api.text)
    return api_data[id]["data"]["name"]

print(second(str(first("1","id"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches that either change the code as per your json response or change the json response on the basis of your code.

1st approach:

```
def first(index):
    return api_data["response"]["info"][index]['id']

def second(moreinfo):
    return api_data[moreinfo]["data"]["name"]
```

JSON:

```
api_data = {'1': {'data': {'name': 'name'}}, 'response': {'info': [{"id": 1, "name": "name"}]}}
```

Function Call:

```
second(""+str(first(0))+"")
```

2nd approach: Based on your given code JSON should be like this.

```
api_data = {'1': {'data': {'name': 'name'}}, 'response': {'info': {'one': {'two': 1}}}}
```

Function Call:

```
second(""+str(first('one', 'two'))+"")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but doesn't help me, and My first function take 2 variable, because giving 2 deferent output from it,

Comment: But it is not possible to get value of key "one" from json because your json does not have key of 'one' or 'two'.

Comment: No JSON have what i want, and as said before, when tried to put number `str(first('one', 'two'))` its get all info i want from number i put.

Comment: But how would you get a value against 'one' or 'two' key if you are not giving it in json? key must be defined in json.

Comment: if you was saying about this, `str(first('one', 'two'))` `one` is id of what i want to get and `two` is what i want to get (ID or Name), `str(first(1, "name"))` this code print the name of what i want.

Comment: you want to get name of id = 1?